Slow Requests and High CPU Laravel VPS and Nuxt Front
I've been experiencing slowness on my VPS server. I have a VPS with 4 CPUs on DigitalOcean and 8 GB of RAM. We have approximately 15,000 users per day. We use Nuxt 3 as the frontend and Laravel as the backend.
Some very simple routes are extremely slow, and I've also noticed that when I run top on my server, php-fpm8.2 uses a lot of CPU. For a few seconds, it takes up 99% or 100%, and sometimes it drops to 30%.


Our website uses OpenAI to summarize texts. We process these texts in a queue to prevent requests from becoming slow. The queue makes requests to OpenAI and then streams the summary in parts via Pusher to the frontend. Some queues can take up to 45 seconds.

In Nuxt, I need the limit and products endpoints. I load them into a plugin to use globally in my application, so I don't have to fetch them multiple times. Instead, I only fetch them the first time the page loads.
Nuxt plugin
init-globals.ts
export default defineNuxtPlugin(async () => {
  const { fetchProducts } = useProducts();
  const { fetchLimits } = useLimits();
  const [limitsResult, productsResult] = await Promise.all([
    fetchLimits(),
    fetchProducts(),
  ]);

  if (limitsResult.error.value) {
    throw createError(limitsResult.error.value);
  }

  if (productsResult.error.value) {
    throw createError(productsResult.error.value);
  }
});

Limits Endpoint
LimitController
class LimitController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {

        $settings = Setting::whereIn('key', [
            Setting::FREE_ESSAY_LIMIT,
            Setting::FREE_QUIZ_LIMIT,
            Setting::FREE_PARAPHRASE_LIMIT_BY_DAY,
            Setting::FREE_SUMMARY_LIMIT_BY_DAY,
            Setting::FREE_SUMMARY_YOUTUBE_LIMIT,
            Setting::FREE_YOUTUBE_LENGTH_SECONDS,
            Setting::FREE_SUMMARY_TEXT_IMAGE_LIMIT,
            Setting::FREE_TEXT_IMAGE_LIMIT,
        ])->get();

        $data = [];

        foreach ($settings as $setting) {
            $data[$setting->key] = $setting->value;
        }

        return response()->json($data);
    }
}

I've also thought that it could be an attack. I have Cloudflare configured with WAF, but I've noticed these logs in /var/log/nginx/access.log:
72.22.150.47 - - [29/Aug/2024:19:13:45 -0600] "\x16\x03\x01\x00\xA3\x01\x00\x00\x9F\x03\x03t\xEA\x9F\xE8\xB3\xDE6\xA5\xF78\xB8$\xA8P\xFC\xA0qd\x95\xBA\xEEyq\x14\x93=KDdX\xA2\x13\x00\x00\x1C\xC0+\xC0,\xCC\xA9\xC0/\xC00\xCC\xA8\xC0\x09\xC0" 400 150 "-" "-" "-"
143.110.222.166 - - [29/Aug/2024:19:15:04 -0600] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 162 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 16_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/16.1 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1" "-"
72.22.150.47 - - [29/Aug/2024:19:18:41 -0600] "\x16\x03\x01\x00\xA3\x01\x00\x00\x9F\x03\x03\xC8\x8ES\x0El\xAE\xBFn\xE6\x93\x95f\x87\xD4k\xBC\xDAP\xD3\x89A\x8F\xDF]\x8E\x8D#\x87\xB0IL}\x00\x00\x1C\xC0+\xC0,\xCC\xA9\xC0/\xC00\xCC\xA8\xC0\x09\xC0" 400 150 "-" "-" "-"
72.22.150.47 - - [29/Aug/2024:19:24:14 -0600] "\x16\x03\x01\x00\xA3\x01\x00\x00\x9F\x03\x03\x9DD(\xC2\x8C{}1\x06\xE1s\x8E\xCE\xDB\xCA\x0E\xF5\x01\xAB\xCF\xD6\xF2[Lg\xDC#\x13(\xC6\xA5<\x00\x00\x1C\xC0+\xC0,\xCC\xA9\xC0/\xC00\xCC\xA8\xC0\x09\xC0" 400 150 "-" "-" "-"
41.82.181.154 - - [29/Aug/2024:19:25:01 -0600] "\x16\x03\x01\x02\x00\x01\x00\x01\xFC\x03\x03t\xFE\xE6U\xD3\x81\xC8JsB\xB5M\xF2\x03\xEDb\xD6\xB0\x89o\x831}\x05\xEAjI\x00\xAAN|\xF7 \x90\xBE\xCAD\x17\xFD\x14\x09>\xF0\xDC\x17\x97\xE5\x85\x08U\x91\xB2\xC9\xDA:<\x11\xF3-\x1F\x19\xEEp\x91" 400 150 "-" "-" "-"
72.22.150.47 - - [29/Aug/2024:19:29:12 -0600] "\x16\x03\x01\x00\xA3\x01\x00\x00\x9F\x03\x03\x1D\xDF\x83\xE7o\xFD\xF6'\x81\xC6\xB1\xEC\xBF\xE5\x99\x5CJ\xE92\xB9\x9B\xFA\x00o\x8CX\x16\x98\xF5\xACc\xAA\x00\x00\x1C\xC0+\xC0,\xCC\xA9\xC0/\xC00\xCC\xA8\xC0\x09\xC0" 400 150 "-" "-" "-"
72.22.150.47 - - [29/Aug/2024:19:34:49 -0600] "\x16\x03\x01\x00\xA3\x01\x00\x00\x9F\x03\x03\xC3+\xFB\x0B=\x227\x89\x1B\xCC\x1BL\xBB?\xF4\x0Cw\xC3\x98\x1A=\xCF\xFBaJ\x11\x03\xCF.\x82\xD6=\x00\x00\x1C\xC0+\xC0,\xCC\xA9\xC0/\xC00\xCC\xA8\xC0\x09\xC0" 400 150 "-" "-" "-"
172.2.76.254 - - [29/Aug/2024:19:39:15 -0600] "\x16\x03\x01\x00\xA7\x01\x00\x00\xA3\x03\x03Vf2\xF0d\xADK\x1EI}\xC6^\x93\xFF,\xD9\xA5>\x15\xB7\x91Xc\xFBu6\xA7JX\xAD9\x12\x00\x00$\xC0+\xC0,\xCC\xA9\xC0/\xC00\xCC\xA8\x00\x9E\x00\x9F\xC0\x09\xC0" 400 150 "-" "-" "-"
172.2.76.254 - - [29/Aug/2024:19:39:17 -0600] "\x16\x03\x01\x00\xA7\x01\x00\x00\xA3\x03\x03\xF4}:\x06\x13[\xD9y\x8D\x89\xA2gK;\xFF3\xF2[" 400 150 "-" "-" "-"
72.22.150.47 - - [29/Aug/2024:19:39:45 -0600] "\x16\x03\x01\x00\xA3\x01\x00\x00\x9F\x03\x03P\x85N\x86\xFB&\xD6\xDAG\xD0Y\xC0\xAE\x8D2\xB5[\x8F\x12\xD8\x01\x04\xDD" 400 150 "-" "-" "-"
72.22.150.47 - - [29/Aug/2024:19:45:29 -0600] "\x16\x03\x01\x00\xA3\x01\x00\x00\x9F\x03\x03\x84\xB2n\xBB*\x8C\xD8)\xA0\xB1i\xD0\x957\x22\xCD\x039\xFCa\x95\xBF]^]W\xB9\x91\x180\x14T\x00\x00\x1C\xC0+\xC0,\xCC\xA9\xC0/\xC00\xCC\xA8\xC0\x09\xC0" 400 150 "-" "-" "-"
92.40.65.137 - - [29/Aug/2024:19:49:47 -0600] "\x16\x03\x01\x00\xA7\x01\x00\x00\xA3\x03\x03\xAB\xB8Nq\x22v\xA3\x9D%\xF2\x1EI\xEE\xFE_F(\xC7a\x1D\xF3\xBC\x13\xA3\x99q\x82J\xC9\xA7\x09\x12\x00\x00$\xC0+\xC0,\xCC\xA9\xC0/\xC00\xCC\xA8\x00\x9E\x00\x9F\xC0\x09\xC0" 400 150 "-" "-" "-"
72.22.150.47 - - [29/Aug/2024:19:50:28 -0600] "\x16\x03\x01\x00\xA3\x01\x00\x00\x9F\x03\x03\x05vO\x03\xE5\xFD\xA3\xE1\x226\x08\xD5\xF9.\xF2mr\x17\x07\xB3h\x0F\xE9\x90]\x08!\xFAD\xF9\xA1\x87\x00\x00\x1C\xC0+\xC0,\xCC\xA9\xC0/\xC00\xCC\xA8\xC0\x09\xC0" 400 150 "-" "-" "-"
72.22.150.47 - - [29/Aug/2024:20:01:22 -0600] "\x16\x03\x01\x00\xA3\x01\x00\x00\x9F\x03\x03\x15\xEA\x95[" 400 150 "-" "-" "-"
57.129.23.166 - - [29/Aug/2024:20:04:42 -0600] "GET /.env HTTP/1.1" 301 162 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.129 Safari/537.36" "-"
57.129.23.166 - - [29/Aug/2024:20:04:43 -0600] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 301 162 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.129 Safari/537.36" "-"
23.242.140.165 - - [29/Aug/2024:20:05:44 -0600] "\x16\x03\x01\x00\xA6\x01\x00\x00\xA2\x03\x03\x11n2UmO\x92\x1B\xDB\xB3z5w\x1D\xD3\xD1\xEE\xB8\x12\xC4\xAA\xD5onl\xD3>w\x01\xA7\x94\x1B\x00\x00\x1C\xC0+\xC0,\xCC\xA9\xC0/\xC00\xCC\xA8\xC0\x09\xC0" 400 150 "-" "-" "-"
72.22.150.47 - - [29/Aug/2024:20:07:03 -0600] "\x16\x03\x01\x00\xA3\x01\x00\x00\x9F\x03\x03Q\xD0Gz\x13\xE7\x1C\x01\xB8x\x0698\x11G\xE9\xC9\xDF\xCD\xF9<\x7F\xC3\x1F\xA2\xEA\x8F\x8C?\xCA\xCA8\x00\x00\x1C\xC0+\xC0,\xCC\xA9\xC0/\xC00\xCC\xA8\xC0\x09\xC0" 400 150 "-" "-" "-"
143.110.222.166 - - [29/Aug/2024:20:09:11 -0600] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 162 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 16_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/16.1 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1" "-"
72.22.150.47 - - [29/Aug/2024:20:12:03 -0600] "\x16\x03\x01\x00\xA3\x01\x00\x00\x9F\x03\x03\x85\xA2C\xA4\xCB\xE0\xFE|G|3\x80A\xC0\xAF%\xB3\xB7\xA7\xAF\xA0De\xCCV\x11\xFCe\x9A.^\xED\x00\x00\x1C\xC0+\xC0,\xCC\xA9\xC0/\xC00\xCC\xA8\xC0\x09\xC0" 400 150 "-" "-" "-"
185.82.219.179 - - [29/Aug/2024:20:14:39 -0600] "GET /conf/.env HTTP/1.0" 404 146 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0" "-"
91.238.181.35 - - [29/Aug/2024:20:15:18 -0600] "\x03\x00\x00/*\xE0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00Cookie: mstshash=Administr" 400 150 "-" "-" "-"

I've also noticed the following in my PHP logs. I have already increased my max_spare_servers and other limits before. Below are my configuration and the logs:
*/etc/php/8.2/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
pm = dynamic

pm.max_children = 40

pm.start_servers = 16

pm.min_spare_servers = 8

pm.max_spare_servers = 32

;pm.max_spawn_rate = 32

;pm.process_idle_timeout = 10s;

;pm.max_requests = 500

[29-Aug-2024 14:03:47] WARNING: [pool www] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 8 children, there are 2 idle, and 12 total children
[29-Aug-2024 14:12:17] WARNING: [pool www] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 8 children, there are 0 idle, and 11 total children
[29-Aug-2024 15:07:16] WARNING: [pool www] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 8 children, there are 2 idle, and 8 total children
[29-Aug-2024 15:12:54] WARNING: [pool www] child 14665, script '/home/ploi/api.mysite.com/public/index.php' (request: "POST /index.php") execution timed out (153.219735 sec), terminating
[29-Aug-2024 15:12:54] WARNING: [pool www] child 14665 exited on signal 15 (SIGTERM) after 184.615188 seconds from start
[29-Aug-2024 15:12:54] NOTICE: [pool www] child 14817 started
[29-Aug-2024 15:47:28] WARNING: [pool www] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 8 children, there are 1 idle, and 8 total children
[29-Aug-2024 16:00:27] NOTICE: Reloading in progress ...
[29-Aug-2024 16:00:27] NOTICE: reloading: execvp("/usr/sbin/php-fpm8.2", {"/usr/sbin/php-fpm8.2", "--nodaemonize", "--fpm-config", "/etc/php/8.2/fpm/php-fpm.conf"})
[29-Aug-2024 16:00:28] NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=8, "/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock"
[29-Aug-2024 16:00:28] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 849
[29-Aug-2024 16:00:28] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
[29-Aug-2024 16:00:28] NOTICE: systemd monitor interval set to 10000ms
[29-Aug-2024 16:18:59] WARNING: [pool www] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 8 children, there are 2 idle, and 9 total children
[29-Aug-2024 17:01:53] WARNING: [pool www] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 8 children, there are 2 idle, and 8 total children
[29-Aug-2024 18:19:52] WARNING: [pool www] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 8 children, there are 0 idle, and 15 total children
[29-Aug-2024 18:19:53] WARNING: [pool www] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 16 children, there are 1 idle, and 18 total children
[29-Aug-2024 18:31:08] WARNING: [pool www] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 8 children, there are 1 idle, and 18 total children
[29-Aug-2024 18:56:12] WARNING: [pool www] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 8 children, there are 2 idle, and 9 total children
[29-Aug-2024 19:10:49] WARNING: [pool www] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 8 children, there are 2 idle, and 10 total children
[29-Aug-2024 20:02:14] WARNING: [pool www] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 8 children, there are 1 idle, and 10 total children
[29-Aug-2024 20:08:24] WARNING: [pool www] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 8 children, there are 2 idle, and 9 total children

Any suggestion?

Looks like PHP is the one being slow here, maybe try to isolate both Laravel and Nuxt. And stress test them locally with a tool to find their shortcomings. Also, if it's not a dedicated VPS, might explain things. Overall, the hardware specs don't look too expensive so if you have that many people, you can always vertical scale it.

Hello, I’ve installed Laravel telescope and I’ll try to stress with pest, I hope to find the bottleneck
